# Handling error Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
import React, {Component, useMemo } from "react";

class TimeslotPicker extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: '',
            loading: false
        };
    }

    createCalendar(year, month) {
        let mon = month - 1; // months in JS are 0..11, not 1..12
        let d = new Date(year, mon);

                let table = '<div className="row">' +
        '<div className="col">MON</div>' +
        '<div classNAme="col">TUE</div>' +
        '<div className="col">WED</div>' +
        '<div className="col">THU</div>' +
        '<div className="col">FRI</div>' +
        '<div className="col">SAT</div>' +
        '<div className="col">SUB</div>' +
        '</div><div className="row">';

        // spaces for the first row
        // from Monday till the first day of the month
        // * * * 1  2  3  4
        for (let i = 0; i < this.getDay(d); i++) {
            table += '<div className="col"></div>';
        }

        // <td> with actual dates
        while (d.getMonth() == mon) {
            table += '<div className="col">' + d.getDate() + '</div>';

            if (this.getDay(d) % 7 == 6) { // sunday, last day of week - newline
                table += '</div><div className="row">';
            }

            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        }

        // add spaces after last days of month for the last row
        // 29 30 31 * * * *
        if (this.getDay(d) != 0) {
            for (let i = this.getDay(d); i < 7; i++) {
                table += '<div className="col"></div>';
            }
        }

        // close the table
        table += '</div></div>';

        return table;
    }

    getDay(date) { // get day number from 0 (monday) to 6 (sunday)
        let day = date.getDay();
        if (day == 0) day = 7; // make Sunday (0) the last day
        return day - 1;
    }


    render () {
        const calendar = this.createCalendar(2022, 9);
        return (
            {calendar}
        )
    }
}

export default TimeslotPicker;
```

I get the following error when running the code "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {calendar}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the error states, your return an object `{calendar}` instead of a valid React element (try just return `calendar`). But never the less, it won't do what you will expect, you will render a string, it looks like you trying to copy vanilla code to React, you should read few tutorials and rewrite this code in a "React way". There are plenty similar question on SO.

Comment: Or you can pass your string to [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) if you know what you doing.

Comment: @DennisVash I felt like you were a bit rude in your comment. I had good intentions when asking for help. If I could find the answer elsewhere, I wouldn't have posted about it. However, your answer was the only one that worked, so thanks.

Comment: I didn't notice that @DennisVash had already answered your question, was busy writing the codesandbox. I guess will leave my answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

If you return single quotes or say backticks with string interpolation, react treats it as a string and not JSX.
What you can do instead is

```
let table = (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">MON</div>
          <div className="col">TUE</div>
          <div className="col">WED</div>
          <div className="col">THU</div>
          <div className="col">FRI</div>
          <div className="col">SAT</div>
          <div className="col">SUB</div>
        </div>
    );
```

Or, you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render HTML from a string with React

For the first approach here's link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-chebyshev-btisk?file=/src/App.js)